# Change TTL for DNS entries on a SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15

Tags: domain-name-system, sles, named-conf

.. preferable without YAST.

I am about migrating several services from a SUSE enterprise server to Ubuntu.

I "found" two DNS related files:

`/var/lib/named/master/domain` with the forward lookups.
`/var/lib/named/master/1.168.192.in-addr.arpa` with the reverse lookups.

In both files there is a `$TTL 2d` - which I need to lower before migrating DNS.

I have not used SUSE recently - is this the right place to edit the files and replace the TTL value or do I have to edit another file?

Or do I have to use YAST and set TTL there?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

These are plain-text files and can be edited using any editor. Depending on whether you have NOTIFY enabled and on the values in your SOA record you might need to change these settings a lot earlier than 2 days before the change to give your slaves the opportunity to fetch this new data as well.

I do not know **yast** but after editing the files, **and increasing the serial number of the SOA record**, simply reload your BIND server, e.g. `service named reload` (on FreeBSD). I do not know which init system SLES uses.

Comment: Thanks - meanwhile the server is shut down and I did the migration - and I went with editing the plain text files - just as you suggested now.

Comment: Yeah, I figured you already solved the issue but wanted to provide an answer in case some one else stumbles upon this question.